# Why does "Suggest Tag Synonyms" require so much rep?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I can understand a restrictive threshold for voting on suggested synonyms, but am curious why it’s so high to initiate suggestions.

For example, I just posted a question about MS Access VBA on Stackoverflow.  When picking my tags, I saw there is [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) and also [microsoft-access](/questions/tagged/microsoft-access).   I checked the synonym pages for both but they aren't listed as synonyms for each other.  Do I need to tag my question with both tags until they become linked?

Comment: This is the same question I wanted to ask after having spotted `dnn` and `dotnetnuke` tags, and not being synonyms. I can submit a wiki description (to be reviewed by someone), but I cannot submit a “should be synonyms” suggestion.

Comment: ... and `cj` and `commission-junction` look like synonyms too. Looks like this question could become the "suggest a synonym" host for low-rep users.

Comment: same thing for [less] and [lesscss]

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is this:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest

We have 2 pages of pending merges.

We have 6 pages of suggested synonyms.

As it stands we can barely handle the current load, let alone add more pending synonyms to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just out of curiosity, does that mean that the tag merge process is not well automated?

Comment: @waffles - The link is currently (Aug/2011) empty. So are there any plans to at least remove that stupid score-of-5-on-the-tag restriction?

Comment: @Martin there are still 6 pages of suggested synonyms http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

Comment: @waffles - Apologies. It displays an empty page there if I'm logged in. I can only see the list when not logged in. *Note*: I see this as a clear indication that the synonym voting system is broken. If we have 6 pages backlog, then something isn't quite right.

Comment: I can also only see the list of pages when logged out. Is this a bug? Further, I'm curious about if this can or should be changed for other SE sites besides SO. I'm more active on AskUbuntu where there are only two pending requests. I'm not sure it would be as big of a deal to lower the rep required for suggesting synonyms there. But maybe it's difficult to change that sort of thing on a site basis.