# Lower the amount of reputation needed to suggest tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, privileges

Today, [**everyone** can suggest post edits](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/). Even unregistered users. But, for some reason, tag synonyms suggestion is very strict, although it's much easier to review - it's only a couple of words.

I think that a good taxonomic system will improve the odds of **finding an answer** and **avoid duplicate questions**.

I'm suggesting to **lower this limit dramatically**. IMO, a 500 rep user is well acquainted with the system and understand the meaning of tag synonyms to suggest some of it's own.

I don't think that you need a score of 5 to understand that [codefirst](/questions/tagged/codefirst), [code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) and [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) are the same (notice that I didn't earn a single point on any of these tags).

---

**Current tag synonyms suggestion policy:**

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can **vote** for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: My suggestion got only 21 views, so it's probably be forgotten. Too bad :(

Comment: Very similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79572/why-does-suggest-tag-synonyms-require-so-much-rep