# Please show me my tag score in places that require it

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-score

The tags related to extending Visual Studio on SO are kind of a mess. There are way more [vspackage](/questions/tagged/vspackage) questions than [visual-studio-package](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-package) so I just edited the 4 [visual-studio-package](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-package) questions to use [vspackage](/questions/tagged/vspackage) instead. I tried proposing a synonym, but apparently I have insufficient tag score. Which surprised me a little, because I'm sure I've answered in one or the other of those tags, but ok.

Then I found that [vsx](/questions/tagged/vsx) which has almost 200 questions has a little cousin [vs-extensibility](/questions/tagged/vs-extensibility) with 47 questions. That's too many to hand-edit and bump. Again I tried with synonyms but no dice on the tag score.

So at least **show me my tag score in the tag**, so I know if I can suggest synonyms or not! Also, if I'm in the much-less used tag, chances are I won't have score there. Should I go to the more-used tag and propose the less-used as a synonym? I'm not sure what direction they work in.

Comment: Your tag scores are shown in [your user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory).

Comment: I know, but that is many clicks away from the "add a synonym" page. (plus, it's in tag score order, so I have to keep clicking Next and looking for the tag) I can check my total rep - it's always at the top. But I can't tell before suggesting whether my suggesting will be ok or not.

Comment: Perhaps the [minimum tag-score should be lowered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80003/152009/)

Comment: Considering that 4 votes are already required for approval, I'm not sure why we need a minimum tag score to suggest synonyms anyway. There are lots of narrow tags created that are hard to earn the token 5 rep in unless you're quite lucky.

Comment: in fact, the more fragmented the topic area across multiple tags (and therefore the more tag synonyms are needed) the harder it is to get some score in those tags.