# What part of tag score do I not understand yet?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-score

I am still wishing I could clean up the VS Extensibility tag situation on SO. (See [Please show me my tag score in places that require it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98606/please-show-me-my-tag-score-in-places-that-require-it) for a description of the problem). And now I believe I have finally achieved the necessary tag score in the [vsx](/questions/tagged/vsx) tag.

[image: tag score]

But, when I triumphantly return to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vsx/synonyms and suggest my synonym:

[image]

I kinda wish this wasn't so hard. But anyway, what am I doing wrong?

**Update: I think the question is actually "when are cached tag scores updated?"**

It has passed over the midnight mark site time and into a new day since I first posted this, and my profile still cheerily tells me I have a tag score of 6 in VSX on 7 questions. But the Top Users page for the tag says I have a score of 2, on 5 questions. So, it's likely that the "are you cleared to suggest synonyms" code checks the same cached values as that page. How often do they update?

Comment: Looks like you are all set to suggest tag synonyms for [tag:vsx] tag. Your name now appears in the leader board.

Comment: Yes indeed, it worked this morning! (Kind of an anticlimax to be honest)

Comment: So what was the consensus here, since I seem to be having the same problem here on Meta. Do we have to wait 24 hours for the tag synonym system to synchronize with the tag score displayed on our profile?

Comment: @Cody you have to wait till about 3am server time - you'll know you've waited long enough when your score on the tag leaderboards matches the score in your profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suspicion is that you just attained the score of more than 5 under [vsx](/questions/tagged/vsx) tag.

You are not yet listed on the top users section even though you have **6** points and **5** pointers are listed in the top users section. Probably, you might want to wait for one more day.

**UPDATE:** Please see the comment posted by Tim Stone.

**UPDATE 2:** Looks like you are all set to suggest tag synonyms for [vsx](/questions/tagged/vsx) tag. Your name now appears in the leader board.

[image]

[image: vsx]

Comment: This is correct. Not because of new up votes, but because the answered questions were only recently (today) retagged with [tag:vsx].

Comment: That sounded like the issue, all right, because I did indeed just attain the score. I noticed that my "extending Visual Studio" kind of answers didn't all have that tag, so I fixed that. However we have now passed over midnight site time and into a new day, and suggesting the synonym still fails. When I check Top Users for the tag I'm still listed with a score of 2. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: @Kate: As far as I know, the top users board is not updated at mid night UTC. It happens much later. You might need to wait for some more time.

Comment: @KateGregory It updates every 24 hours, usually three hours after midnight UTC (if I recall correctly).