# Why can't I suggest or vote for a tag synonym, when I have enough reputation in the source tag?

Tags: discussion, reputation, tag-synonyms

On StackOverflow, there's a proposal to make [xcode6-beta4 a synonym of xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode6/synonyms). I have a score of [26 in xcode6-beta4 but only 4 in xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23649/jtbandes?tab=tags&sort=name&page=13). Yet when I try to vote for the synonym, I get

> You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym

Why isn't my reputation on xcode6 taken into consideration here?

Comment: Why don't you just retag one of your xcode6-beta4 Q or As with sufficient rep to tip you over to xcode6?  As long as you recorded in the question body that you were using xcode6-beta4 that important piece of information will not be lost.

Comment: If you do, be aware you will have to wait for a cache to update before you can use your powers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100948/what-part-of-tag-score-do-i-not-understand-yet ,

Answer (score 1):

You need a score of 5, so you can make a synonym this way:

```
xcode6-beta4 => xcode6
```

but not this way:

```
xcode6 => xcode6-beta4
```