# Merge tags: fusion-tables google-tables google-fusion-tables

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request, synonym-request

Since 2500 reputation is well out of reach, I am writing to suggest a merge of
[fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/fusion-tables), [google-tables](/questions/tagged/google-tables), and [google-fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables).

With google-tables just getting deleted (since both current posts also use [fusion-tables])

See also
[Why does "Suggest Tag Synonyms" require so much rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79572/why-does-suggest-tag-synonyms-require-so-much-rep)
I think that 2500 rep is way too high for merge requests: many cases of tag merges are easy, clear, compelling, and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/fusion-tables) looks like a sponsored tag, I retagged all current [google-fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables) to [fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/fusion-tables).  (Something that you can also do via the suggested edit process.)

After a few days of no use, [google-fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables) should drop out and not be usable until recreated, again, by [a user with 1500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags).

(Note that there are [currently no users (except mods and devs) who have both 2500 rep and a 5 score in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fusion-tables/topusers).  That is, who can propose synonyms.)

It's not clear to me that all [google-tables](/questions/tagged/google-tables) are also [fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/fusion-tables).

---

**Update:**  Upon closer inspection, retagged all but 2 of the [google-tables](/questions/tagged/google-tables) questions (and voted to close 1 of those 2).